# self-reference within declaration of a structured javascript variable

Tags: javascript, json, oop, variables

Suppose I declare a structured Javascript variable like this:

```
var mydata = {'list':[
{'fname':'george','lname':'washington'}
,{'fname':'oscar','lname':'wilde'}
,{'fname':'james','lname':'polk'}
]
,'summary':this.list[1]['lname']
}
```

Question: How can I ensure that

```
this.list[1]['lname']
```

equals 'wilde' and that my "this" is actually referring 
to what I intend?

Comment: Note: I remember actually seeing someone do something like this in a stack overflow answer and saying "AHA!" to myself, but I cannot remember the post url.

Comment: You may be refering to one of these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+aha

Comment: heh ... that's funny ^_^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also make this work in a function.

```
var mydata = {'list':[
{'fname':'george','lname':'washington'}
,{'fname':'oscar','lname':'wilde'}
,{'fname':'james','lname':'polk'}
]
,'summary':function(){return this.list[1]['lname']}
}

alert(mydata.summary());
```

Answer (score 5):

this won't work as written, but you could do:

```
var mydata = {'list':[
{'fname':'george','lname':'washington'}
,{'fname':'oscar','lname':'wilde'}
,{'fname':'james','lname':'polk'}
]
}   

mydata.summary = mydata.list[1]['lname'];
```